# Android ListView Refresh Single Row

Tags: android, performance, listview

After I have gotten the data for a single row of a `ListView`, I want to update that single row.

Currently I am using `notifyDataSetChanged();` but that makes the `View` react very slowly.  Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One option is to manipulate the `ListView` directly. First check if the index of the updated row is between `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()`, these two give you the first and last positions in the adapter that are visible on the screen. Then you can get the row `View` with `getChildAt(int index)` and change it.

Comment: Thanks. This would work if I am **editing** the current layout of the child. But what if I want to **change the layout altogether** (by inflating a different xml)? If I call `newView(...)` on the adapter, it gives me a different view which however is not put in the `listView`.

Comment: @hadi you should take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11568271/858626

Answer (score 90):

As Romain Guy [explained a while back](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=45m46s) during the [Google I/O session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html), the most efficient way to only update one view in a list view is something like the following (this one update the whole view data):

```
ListView list = getListView();
int start = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
for(int i=start, j=list.getLastVisiblePosition();i<=j;i++)
    if(target==list.getItemAtPosition(i)){
        View view = list.getChildAt(i-start);
        list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);
        break;
    }
```

Assuming `target` is one item of the adapter.

This code retrieve the `ListView`, then browse the currently shown views, compare the `target` item you are looking for with each displayed view items, and if your target is among those, get the enclosing view and execute the adapter `getView` on that view to refresh the display.

As a side note `invalidate` doesn't work like some people expect and will not refresh the view like getView does, `notifyDataSetChanged` will rebuild the whole list and end up calling `getview` for every displayed items and `invalidateViews` will also affect a bunch.

One last thing, one can also get extra performance if he only needs to change a child of a row view and not the whole row like `getView` does. In that case, the following code can replace `list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);` (example to change a `TextView` text):

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myid)).setText("some new text");
```

In code we trust.

Comment: You should probably just link your other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9987616/1026132 instead of copying and pasting here. This would help to reduce the amount of duplicate content in SO.

Comment: how to implement this with different view type?

Comment: Link to "Google I/O session" in answer is dead.

Comment: seems awesome! I'm gonna try this today

Comment: maybe sometimes you need to use "list.getAdapter().getView(i - list.getHeaderviewCount, view, list);" instead of "list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);"

Answer (score 30):

This simpler method works well for me, and you only need to know the position index to get ahold of the view:

```
// mListView is an instance variable

private void updateItemAtPosition(int position) {
    int visiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = mListView.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
    mListView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, mListView);
}
```

Comment: i will send that updated values to detailview another page if user do changes on that details page how to update  back to list please

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me.  Note when calling GetChild() you have to offset by the first item in the list since its relative to that.

```
int iFirst = getFirstVisiblePosition();
int iLast = getLastVisiblePosition();

if ( indexToChange >= numberOfRowsInSection() ) {
    Log.i( "MyApp", "Invalid index. Row Count = " + numberOfRowsInSection() );
}
else {      
    if ( ( index >= iFirst ) && ( index <= iLast ) ) {
        // get the view at the position being updated - need to adjust index based on first in the list
        View vw = getChildAt( sysvar_index - iFirst );
        if ( null != vw ) {
            // get the text view for the view
            TextView tv = (TextView) vw.findViewById(com.android.myapp.R.id.scrollingListRowTextView );
            if ( tv != null ) {
                // update the text, invalidation seems to be automatic
                tv.setText( "Item = " + myAppGetItem( index ) + ". Index = " + index + ". First = " + iFirst + ". Last = " + iLast );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this example `sysvar_index` means the position of the row you want to update

Answer (score 2):

There is another much more efficient thing you can do, if it fits your use-case that is.

If you are changing the state and can somehow call the proper (by knowing the position) `mListView.getAdapter().getView()` it will the most efficient of all.

I can demonstrate a really easy way to do it, by creating an anonymous inner class in my `ListAdapter.getView()` class. In this example I have a `TextView` showing a text "new" and that view is set to `GONE` when the list item is clicked:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View view = convertView;

    Object quotation = getItem(position);
    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    if (view == null)
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_quotation, parent, false);

    final TextView newTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newTextView);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCallbacks != null)
                mCallbacks.onItemSelected(quotation.id);
            if (!quotation.isRead()) {
                servicesSingleton.setQuotationStatusReadRequest(quotation.id);
                quotation.setStatusRead();
                newTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    if(quotation.isRead())
        newTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        newTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
}
```

The framework automatically uses the correct `position` and you do have to worry about fetching it again before calling `getView`.

Answer (score 0):

For me below line worked:

Arraylist.set(position,new ModelClass(value));

Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score -2):

Just for the record, did anyone consider the 'View view' on the override method ?

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    //Update the selected item
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cardText2)).setText("done!");

                }
```

Comment: The question was how to refresh a single row in the ListView at any given moment. onItemClick is only called when the users click an item and so does not suffice