# Redraw a single row in a listview

Tags: android, listview, view, android-arrayadapter, redraw

Is it possible to redraw a single row in a `ListView`? I have a `ListView` with rows that are `LinearLayout`s. I listen to a preference change and sometimes I need to change just one `View` inside the `LinearLayout` of a single row. Is there a way to make it redraw that row without calling `listview.notifyDatasetChanged()`?

I've tried calling view.invalidate() on the view (inside the `LinearLayout`) but it doesn't redraw the row.

Comment: "Is there a way to make it redraw that row without calling listview.notifydatasetchanged()?" -- just find it as a child of the `ViewGroup` (in this case, `ListView`) and modify it. "I've tried calling view.invalidate() on the view (inside the linearlayout) but it doesn't redraw the row." -- are you sure you have the proper row? You should not even need to call `invalidate()`, AFAIK.

Comment: I definitely have the right row, and the right view. I think my problem is my preference listener is being garbage collected. I changed it so I call notifyDataSetChanged() in my activity's onResume(), which solves the problem I was trying to fix.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

As Romain Guy [explained a while](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=45m46s) back during the [Google I/O session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html), the most efficient way to only update one view in a list view is something like the following (this one update the whole `View` data):

```
ListView list = getListView();
int start = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
for(int i=start, j=list.getLastVisiblePosition();i<=j;i++)
    if(target==list.getItemAtPosition(i)){
        View view = list.getChildAt(i-start);
        list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);
        break;
    }
```

Assuming `target` is one item of the adapter.

This code retrieve the `ListView`, then browse the currently shown views, compare the `target` item you are looking for with each displayed view items, and if your target is among those, get the enclosing view and execute the adapter `getView()` on that view to refresh the display.

As a side note `invalidate()` doesn't work like some people expect and will not refresh the view like `getView()` does, `notifyDataSetChanged()` will rebuild the whole list and end up calling `getview()` for every displayed items and `invalidateViews()` will also affect a bunch.

One last thing, one can also get extra performance if he only needs to change a child of a row view and not the whole row like `getView` does. In that case, the following code can replace `list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);` (example to change a `TextView` text):

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myid)).setText("some new text");
```

In code we trust.

Comment: Could you please add link to the Google I/O session itself? I want to check whole session.

Comment: +1 thx for this, its interesting - im presuming it works as your passing the current view in as the convertView arg and it will have its view elements reset - very nice

Comment: Shouldn't here be i<j instead of i<=j ?

Comment: I am facing same issue. But  list.getChildAt(position) return child based on indexing of what displaying on scree. I have mention question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29429704/2624806. any suggestion!

Comment: Hi, I have used this code ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myid)).setText("some new text");  and it worked.But when I scrolled down the listview and comes back the text will be old one not the updated text.

Comment: Your answer is working perfectly for me. But screen refreshes and moving to top of screen? Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: @ Ranjith 
That's because, when you scrolling up and down, the adapter's `getView()` method gets called, and, if you haven't changed your data for that row, it will redraw with the "old" one.

Answer (score 6):

The `view.invalidate()` didn't work for me. But this works like a charm:

supose you are updating the position "`position`" in the row.
The `if` avoid weird redraws stuffs, like text dancing when you are
updating a row that are not in the screen.

```
            if (position >= listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
                && position <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition()) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listView.invalidateViews();
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Comment: It is working dude :) but It seems to recreate all the rows... any way to recreate single row??

Answer (score 3):

Romain Guy answered to this question at "Google IO 2010 The world of ListView" 
Video at the exact time where this question was asked : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=3149s

So according to Romain Guy, that should work, and I think we can trust him.

The reason why your view is not redrawn is a bit mysterious.
Maybe try disabling all cache options available in listView

```
setAnimationCacheEnabled(false);
setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
setChildrenDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
setChildrenDrawnWithCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This is not what he said. He said that the method getView will still be called but when generating the ui the engine can see that the items data has not changed, and is then reusing them.

Answer (score 0):

Put some tag on the row that you want to update.
When you want to redraw that specific view or row then do

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(....)
```

and then

```
View v = lv.findViewWithTag(tagobject);
```

and then you do whatever you want with the view.