# ListView Updating a single row

Tags: java, android

I want to update a single row in my listview with different content once i press a button. I know i can use `notifydatasetchanged(`) but that would update the whole `listView`.

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987616/1552551) and it fits perfectly for what I want to do.

I have done a listview with 5 rows and when I press the button I want to update the 4th row with a different text. I dont want to set the text programatically since this is just a dummy project just to see if refreshing a single row is possible and my real project is much more complex than just a `textview`.

So my question is: can i use `getView()` to update a single row in a `listview`?

Here is my code:

*my Activity:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ListView list1;
    public listAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        adapter = new listAdapter(this);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.setText("Different text");
                View row2Update = list1.getChildAt(3);
                list1.getAdapter().getView(3, row2Update, list1);

            }
        });

    } 

}
```

*My adapter :*

```
public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public Activity activity;
    public String text="Normal Text";

    public listAdapter(Activity activity){

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout rowView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
        textView.setText(text);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This is what the activity looks like:

[image: Activity snapshot]

But when I press my button nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** call the **getView()** method of the adapter yourself. The adapter's getView() method is is only called, when

- The listview is create
- when the user scrolls the list view
- when notifysetdatachanged() is called.

  All these are done by the OS. GetView() is called for all the rows in the listview. It is not called for just a single row. So, if you want to change the rows, you have to provide the data again in a `String[]`, `ArrayList<>` etc
  If you want different text to appear for for a single row, onClick() of a button - you can do this

  public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

  ```
  public Activity activity;
  public ArrayList<String> text;

  public listAdapter(Activity activity){

      this.activity = activity;
  }

  public void setText(ArrayList<String> text){
      this.text = text;
  }

  public int getCount() {
      return 5;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {

      return null;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
      LinearLayout rowView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
      TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
      textView.setText(text[position]);
      return rowView;
  }
  ```

  }

  And in your Activity :

  ```
  list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
  adapter = new listAdapter(this);
  String[] entries={"Normal Text","Normal Text","Normal Text","Normal text","Normal text"};
  ArrayList<String> text=Arrays.asList(entries);
  adapter.setText(text);
  list1.setAdapter(adapter);

  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
         text.set(3,"Different Text");
          adapter.setText(text);
          list1.setAdapter(adapter);

      }
  });
  ```

  There is another way of doing it also as @Andy suggested in one of the comments :

  ```
  listViewPeople.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long l) {
               //IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE CONTENT OF THE ROW CLICKED
         if(position == someNumber) {
                 text.set(position,"different Text");
                 list1.setAdapter(text);
         }
      }
  });
  ```

Sorry for the bold text. For some reason the **CTRL+K** is not working for the above code.

Comment: Great answer. I agree with you. Another thing he could do is just set onItemClickListener to the ListView itself, and if the position is whatever (assuming you don't use a button), you just update the list in the adapter. Of course ultimately he needs to figure out which option is best for him.

Comment: @Andy : You are right. Actually that would be better Idea. But since, he specifically asked to change the row content on click of a button, I went for this.

Comment: :) Oh no, you are technically right @Ashwin just because its more efficient. There isn't any unnecessary work being done. Since he only wants to update a single line. But he does mention that this is only a test, so I figure he should also have another method incase he wants more to be updated.

Comment: @Andy : okay. I will put it up:)

Comment: yeah I though i could use the getView() method  in my activity and it would be the same as if i performed a scroll, but I guess the only way to achieve a single row update is to set the content of the row manually as you suggest

Comment: @BigBen3216 : yeah...you can go through the source code of listview.setAdapter(), to see if there is any workaround- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29 .Do tell me if you find out something.