# Android Array Adaper Item Update

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am trying to impliment a simple chat app based on the following article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/897826/Designing-Android-Chat-Bubble-Chat-UI

I have managed to get my chat working fine,

this is my sequence of events...

Send new message to a MySql Db and return a JSON with the status that the message was delivered, I then send a GCM message to the reciving device that is listining for a broadast reciever and fires off a function to Add a new message. all this is fine and dandy, once the mesage is downloaed from the server i fire a GCM back to the sender to notify that the message has been read. This is where i am stuck :(

How would i update the already populated listview to show the change?

something like i.e:

```
// Do a JSON call for the current user
No Problem here

// See if the status has changed
???????????????
//Do the Update
??????????????
update (Int msgID){
// here i need to update the imageview
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Please see the base code below.

ChatActivity

```
public class ChatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText messageET;
    private ListView messagesContainer;
    private Button sendBtn;
    private ChatAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatHistory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls() {
        messagesContainer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesContainer);
        messageET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chatSendButton);

        TextView meLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meLbl);
        TextView companionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friendLabel);
        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        companionLabel.setText("My Buddy");// Hard Coded
        loadDummyHistory();

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageText = messageET.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
                    return;
                }

                ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
                chatMessage.setId(122);//dummy
                chatMessage.setMessage(messageText);
                chatMessage.setDate(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
                chatMessage.setMe(true);

                messageET.setText("");

                displayMessage(chatMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayMessage(ChatMessage message) {
        adapter.add(message);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        scroll();
    }

    private void scroll() {
        messagesContainer.setSelection(messagesContainer.getCount() - 1);
    }

    private void loadDummyHistory(){

        chatHistory = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();

        ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
        msg.setId(1);
        msg.setMe(false);
        msg.setMessage("Hi");
        msg.setDate(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
        chatHistory.add(msg);
        ChatMessage msg1 = new ChatMessage();
        msg1.setId(2);
        msg1.setMe(false);
        msg1.setMessage("How r u doing???");
        msg1.setDate(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
        chatHistory.add(msg1);

        adapter = new ChatAdapter(ChatActivity.this, new ArrayList<ChatMessage>());
        messagesContainer.setAdapter(adapter);

                for(int i=0; i<chatHistory.size(); i++) {
                    ChatMessage message = chatHistory.get(i);
                    displayMessage(message);
                }
    }
}
```

ChatMessage

```
public class ChatMessage {
    private long id;
    private boolean isMe;
    private String message;
    private Long userId;
    private String dateTime;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public boolean getIsme() {
        return isMe;
    }
    public void setMe(boolean isMe) {
        this.isMe = isMe;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDate(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

ChatAdapter

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private Activity context;

    public ChatAdapter(Activity context, List<ChatMessage> chatMessages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (chatMessages != null) {
            return chatMessages.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ChatMessage getItem(int position) {
        if (chatMessages != null) {
            return chatMessages.get(position);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        ChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_message, null);
            holder = createViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        boolean myMsg = chatMessage.getIsme() ;//Just a dummy check 
                //to simulate whether it me or other sender
        setAlignment(holder, myMsg);
        holder.txtMessage.setText(chatMessage.getMessage());
        holder.txtInfo.setText(chatMessage.getDate());

        return convertView;
    }

    public void add(ChatMessage message) {
        chatMessages.add(message);
    }

    public void add(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
        chatMessages.addAll(messages);
    }

    private void setAlignment(ViewHolder holder, boolean isMe) {
        if (!isMe) {
            holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);
            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        } else {
            holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_message_bg);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);
            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    private ViewHolder createViewHolder(View v) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        holder.content = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.content);
        holder.contentWithBG = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);
        holder.txtInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        return holder;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtMessage;
        public TextView txtInfo;
        public LinearLayout content;
        public LinearLayout contentWithBG;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

K-

EDIT:

The main problem was how to get the ID from the already created listview, This was clearly shown in the Acepted answer.

however instead of

```
chatMessages.get(i).id == message.id
```

i had to use

```
chatMessages.get(i).getId() == message.getId()
```

but this is a simple soloution and really works as expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redraw a single row in a listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075975/redraw-a-single-row-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update only one row (faster, more code) or update all visible rows with `notifyDataSetChanged()`(slower, less code).

```
ChatMessage message = ...; // updated message
adapter.update(message);
// update only one row
int start = messagesContainer.getFirstVisiblePosition();
for (int i = start, j = messagesContainer.getLastVisiblePosition(); i <= j; i++) {
    if (message.id == adapter.getItem(i).id){
        View view = messagesContainer.getChildAt(i-start);
        adapter.getView(i, view, messagesContainer);
        break;
    }
}
// end of update only one row

// adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // to update all visible rows
```

Where `adapter.update()` is:

```
public void update(ChatMessage message) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chatMessages.size(); i++) {
      if (chatMessages.get(i).id == message.id) {
        chatMessages.set(i, message);
        break;
      }   
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

When you change `chatMessages` list you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of `BaseAdapter`:

```
public void add(ChatMessage message) {
    chatMessages.add(message);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void add(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
    chatMessages.addAll(messages);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); is called in ChatActivity on adding a new message. (displayMessage), This works 100%, my Problem is how would i change an already added and displayed message?

Comment: @Kenny So you need to update `ListView` item for message that is already in adapter?

Comment: That is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: add new field to ChatMessage "isRead" and when received notification mentioning opponent has read, get ChatMessage by its' id (update isRead = true) and notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: @Khawar Please could you post a sample, i am not sure how to get the message by its ID

Comment: @mixel This seems like a logical Soloution, Thank you i will try it and let you know how it functions

Comment: @mixel Once again Thank you very much, this is pure genius, i have tried everything in the past 5 days with no luck, your soloution works a treat. :)

Comment: @Kenny, when you receive a message, must have some id and save in DB and when you read that message, just update message isRead and notify your listview