# remove item from ListView without changing related database

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-adapterview

I have a `CursorAdapter` which fetch data from `SQLite` Database and provides views for a list. Now I want to delete an item in list without deleting data from DB. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987616/1043882), it is possible to change view of specific item without changing the data-set. But `removeViewAt(int index)` is not supported in `ListView`. Is it possible to remove an item without changing DB?

Comment: remove it from ArrayList object that populated from Db

Comment: @Amrnoid Here list uses `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: Are you able to add a new column with a boolean for `deleted`? You can change your adapter's `getView()` to hide those rows where `deleted == true`.

Comment: try to append  the deleted id of item in select query with not equal statement

Comment: @dharms How I can hide those rows?

Comment: Set the row's visibility to `GONE`.

Comment: @Amrnoid Yes, it is an option that must work which I did not think about that. But I wait for a way without need to re-querying the DB.

Comment: @dharms setting visibility of view of row to `GONE` leaves the row empty; but the empty row and its bounds are visible.

Comment: @Amrnoid Please add your comment as answer, so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: thnx , i hope it solved your problem

Comment: You need to do it to row's parent view. If you are doing a child view it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to append the deleted id of item in select query with not equal statement