# Why my listview adapter doesn't show the right layout on new view?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom Cursor Adapter that is based off of the MMS and SMS database in android. code looks like this as follows:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    Message m = Message.getMessage(context, cursor); // gets message from cursor
    int t = m.getType(); // this gets the type of message it is .. 2 = recv, 1 = sent

    switch(t){
    case Message.MMS_IN: // 128
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_item_recv, parent, false);
    case Message.MMS_OUT: // 132
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_item_sent, parent, false);
    case Message.SMS_IN: // 2
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_item_recv, parent, false);
    case Message.SMS_OUT: // 1
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_item_sent, parent, false);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `R.layout.messagelist_item_sent` is for sent messages and the `R.layout.messagelist_item_recv` is for received messages. 
But looking at my messages, the rows that are first shown when the listview are shown correctly, but when I go up the listview to new views, the layouts are mixed up. The recv layout is where the sent layout is supposed to be and vice versa. Any one know why this kind of problem would be occuring?

*** EDIT ****

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     // move the cursor to the position
Cursor c = (Cursor)getItem(position);
Message m = Message.getMessage(context, c);

if (isInbox(m.getType())){
   inflater.inflate(recv view);
 // it's been shortened 
} else {
   inflater.inflate(send view);   
// and determine the correct type of row layout
     // return 0 or 1
     // use the code that you currently have from the newView method
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `getView(...)` as well? Items in a `ListView` are recycled as it is scrolled. For instance, if the list can only show 10 items, then only 10 item views will ever be created. As the list is scrolled, the previous item view at any given position is passed to the `getView` method as the `convertView` parameter. You would then use that existing `convertView` and inflate into it whichever list item layout you need.

Comment: thanks for that hint. So what would the code look like exactly? in the getView(...) code would I check to see if the convertView is null and if so then check the message type and then inflate the view again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But looking at my messages, the rows that are first shown when the
>   listview are shown correctly, but when I go up the listview to new
>   views, the layouts are mixed up.

That is probably happening because you don't handle the `ListView` recycling mechanism right. The `newView` method is not called for each row, it's called when there isn't a recycled view to be used for the row layout(like when the `ListView` is first shown, that's why the rows appear in the correct order). Otherwise, the `ListView` will use a recycled view which may or may not be the right type of view.

You should use the methods `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`. The method `getViewTypeCount()` will return two(as you have two types of rows?!?) and then implement the logic to determine the correct row type in the `getItemViewType`:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     Cursor c = (Cursor)getItem(position);
     Message m = Message.getMessage(context, c);
     switch(m.getType()){
         case Message.MMS_IN: // 128
             return 1;
         case Message.MMS_OUT: // 132
             return 0;
         case Message.SMS_IN: // 2
             return 1;
         case Message.SMS_OUT: // 1
             return 0;
         default:
             return 0;
      }
}
```

Then in the `newView` method:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    int rowType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
    if (rowType == 0){
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_item_sent, parent, false);
    } else if (rowType == 1){    
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_item_recv, parent, false);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```