# Android ListView Refresh Single Row - Should I hide ListView from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I am refering [Android ListView Refresh Single Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123083/android-listview-refresh-single-row)

However, to use the above link technique, I have to make `ListView` visible to `ArrayAdapter`.

Currently, in order to have a very optimized way to update display in `ListView`, I need to do this to my `ArrayAdapter`

```
public PortfolioArrayAdapter(ListView listView, Activity activity, List<TransactionSummary> transactionSummaries) {
    super(activity, R.layout.portfolio_management_row_layout, transactionSummaries);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listView = listView;
    ...
}

// Do not use notifyDataSetChanged, as it will refresh entire ListView.
// We only want to update certain row.
private void refreshView(final int row) {
    final int firstVisiblePosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastVisiblePosition = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if (row < firstVisiblePosition || row > lastVisiblePosition) {
        return;
    }
    this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final View view = listView.getChildAt(row - firstVisiblePosition);
            // Refresh?
            getView(row, view, listView);                
        }
    });
}
```

---

However, I feel uncomfortable to pass `ListView` reference to `ArrayAdapter`, as I thought they should be independent from each others? (Due to MVC?)

Is there any better way I can let *ListView Refresh Single Row*?

In Java Swing, they did it in a pretty neat way. They provide the following method for a table model.

[fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29)

So, that model can tell view which row and col is being affected, without knowing who the view is.

In Andorid, my model (`ArrayAdapter`) needs to know, `ListView` is the view, only then my model can talk to the view.

Comment: As far as i know, all you can do is update dataset and notify adapter via notifyDatasetChanged(). Still if there is a performance problem (hard to create one on list view :P), you might hold a weak reference to it for direct access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think your ArrayAdapter shouldn't be able to have a reference to your ListView. ListView is your View and ArrayAdapter your Model, so they need to interact. From wikipedia:

> A model notifies its associated views and controllers when there has
>   been a change in its state. This notification allows the views to
>   produce updated output, and the controllers to change the available
>   set of commands

Isn't this exactly how the principle of listeners work, you add the view to a list of listening objects and notify them on any change.

Comment: Theory of MVC is that, model and view should be seperated from each others. If u did Java swing programming on their table, u will know what I mean. If you look at my updated post regarding Swing, you will know why I am having this concern.

Comment: Yes, separated as in different classes and be able to use the model for different views and vica versa, you can still use a different view. But that doesn't change when you reference the view in the model.


This site explains it well: http://www.moock.org/lectures/mvc/
Look at object references in mvc.