# Update buttons in CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

Question is i'm trying to update all the buttons in by listview, buttons are in CustomAdapter which i've written, but buttons are not being updated. So the idea is to change the text of all buttons in the ListView and show the timer after button was clicked, can anyone tell what i'm doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    int secs, mins;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Button buttonShare;
        TextView title;
        ImageView poster;
        View itemView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            itemView = convertView;
        }

        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Настраиваем текстовые поля
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        buttonShare = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postButton);


        // ImageView
        poster = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.adImage);

        title.setText(resultp.get(AdsFragment.TAG_TITLE));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(AdsFragment.TAG_PHOTO), poster);
        buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Boolean posted = AdsFragment.getPosted();
                if (posted == false) {
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, BroadcastService.class));
                    Log.i("SERVICE", "Started service");
                    cdt.start();
                    //updateGUI(buttonShare);

                } else {
                    Log.i("POST", "WAS POSTED!!!");
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("LALKA")
                            .setMessage("LALKA").setCancelable(true).show();
                }

            }
        });

        CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                secs = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                buttonShare.setText(" " + mins + " : " + String.format("%02d", secs));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }

        };


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have `//updateGUI(buttonShare);` commented the method call

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal i'm not using this method for now i need to start a timer in all buttons.

Comment: so you want to start a countdown timer for every button when it is clicked ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal yes, and update text on all the buttons from listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this methode [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Boolean posted = AdsFragment.getPosted();
        if (posted == false) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, BroadcastService.class));
            Log.i("SERVICE", "Started service");
            CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                secs = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                buttonShare.setText(" " + mins + " : " + String.format("%02d", secs));

            }
            cdt.start();
            //updateGUI(buttonShare);

        } else {
            Log.i("POST", "WAS POSTED!!!");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("LALKA")
                    .setMessage("LALKA").setCancelable(true).show();
        }

    }
        });
```

Comment: It will update only button which i clicked, but i need all the buttons from the listview.

Comment: for that you will need to run a for loop for every list item button to `setText()` inside the CountdownTimer `View v = listViewItems.getChildAt(position - listViewItems.getFirstVisiblePosition());`
Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9987714/3326331)

Answer (score 1):

to update the data in your adapter you need to use [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and regarding with the views you need to use [invalidateviews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)