# PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

am building an open source project, here is its link

http://slidese.github.io/slidese/2013/11/25/update_listview_item.html

I've imported all library projects which it is using into eclipse. All are fine except PullToRefresh library. it is giving me the error "PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener cannot be resolved to a type" where fragment implements it
2nd error is at

```
mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(mListview, this);
```

it says "The method addRefreshableView(View, ViewDelegate) in the type PullToRefreshAttacher is not applicable for the arguments (ListView, ContentFragment)"

3rd error is at

```
@Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DownloaderService.class);
        intent.putExtra(DownloaderService.EXTRA_USER_INITIATED, true);
        getActivity().startService(intent);

}
```

It is asking me to remove override annotation. here is complete code of fragment.

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment implements PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener {

    private final String TAG = "ContentFragment";

    public static final String CONTENT_MODE = "content_mode";

    public static final int MODE_ADFREE = 0;
    public static final int MODE_PREMIUM = 1;

    private StartActivity mListener;
    private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;
    private UpdaterAsyncTask mUpdater;
    private int mScrollState = OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

    ListView mListview;
    Button mPlayButton;
    ContentAdapter mAdapter;
    int mMode;
    Map<String, UpdateHolder> mUpdates = new HashMap<String, UpdateHolder>();

    public ContentFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mListener = (StartActivity) activity;
            Log.d(TAG, "Attached podcast list fragment");

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must be the StartActivity");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, null);

        mListview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListview.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty_list_view));
        mListview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        mListview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu_content, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {

                    SparseBooleanArray checked = mListview.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    Content[] params = new Content[checked.size()];
                    int index = 0;
                    int first = mListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    int last = mListview.getLastVisiblePosition();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mListview.getCount(); i++) {
                        if (checked.get(i)) {
                            params[index++] = (Content)mListview.getItemAtPosition(i);

                            if (i >= first && i <= last) {
                                View view = mListview.getChildAt(i-first);

                                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                                animation.setDuration(200);
                                //animation.setFillAfter(true);
                                animation.setStartOffset(100 * (index) );
                                view.startAnimation(animation);    
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    new AsyncTask<Content, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Content... params) {
                            for (Content content : params) {
                                File file = Utils.getFilepath(content.getFilename());
                                file.delete();
                            }

                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            super.onPostExecute(result);

                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);

                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            }
        });

        mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
                Content content = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                mListener.showContentDetails(content);
            }
        });

        mListview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                mScrollState = scrollState;

            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }

        });

        mPullToRefreshAttacher = ((StartActivity) getActivity()).getPullToRefreshAttacher();
        mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(mListview, this);

        mMode = getArguments().getInt(CONTENT_MODE);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mUpdater != null)
            mUpdater.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateAdapter();

        mUpdater = new UpdaterAsyncTask();
        mUpdater.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void)null);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        updateAdapter();
    }

    public void replaceCurrentlyPlayingContent() {
        GlobalContext.INSTANCE.replaceCurrentlyPLayingContent(mAdapter.getObjects(), mListener.getCurrentTrack());
    }

    private void updateAdapter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateAdapter");

        //new FetchContentAsyncTask(mMode).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        final String mp3 = mListener.getSavedStateMp3();
        final boolean isPlaying = mListener.getSavedStateIsPlaying();
        final boolean isPaused = mListener.getSavedStateIsPaused();

        List<Content> listOfContent = GlobalContext.INSTANCE.getCachedContent(mMode, mp3, isPlaying, isPaused);

        mAdapter = new ContentAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_card, listOfContent);
        mListview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DownloaderService.class);
        intent.putExtra(DownloaderService.EXTRA_USER_INITIATED, true);
        getActivity().startService(intent);

    }

    private class UpdaterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        boolean isRunning = true;

        public void stop() {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            while (isRunning) {

                /*
                Map<String, UpdateHolder> map = gatherMetadata();
                publishProgress(map);
                */

                updateCurrentAdapterContent();
                publishProgress();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
            super.onProgressUpdate();

            if (mScrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123083/android-listview-refresh-single-row
                int start = mListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for(int i = start, j = mListview.getLastVisiblePosition(); i<=j; i++) {
                    View view = mListview.getChildAt(i-start);
                    if (((Content)mListview.getItemAtPosition(i)).dirty) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Content is dirty");
                        mListview.getAdapter().getView(i, view, mListview);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void updateCurrentAdapterContent() {

        List<Content> listOfContent = mAdapter.getObjects();
        Map<String, UpdateHolder> map = new HashMap<String, UpdateHolder>();

        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        q.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING | DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
        try {
            Cursor cursor = ContentDownloadManager.INSTANCE.query(q);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                //long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID));
                String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI));
                int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                int downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                float progress = (float)downloaded/(float)total;

                UpdateHolder holder = new UpdateHolder();
                holder.progress = progress;
                holder.status = status;

                map.put(uri, holder);
            }

            cursor.close();

            final Content currentContent = mListener.getCurrentTrack();
            final boolean isPlaying = mListener.isPlaying();
            final boolean isPaused = mListener.isPaused();

            for (Content content : listOfContent) {
                // First update any download progress we might have for this specific content item
                UpdateHolder holder = map.get(content.mp3);
                if (holder != null) {
                    if (content.downloadProgress != holder.progress) {
                        content.downloadProgress = holder.progress;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                    if (content.downloadStatus != holder.status) {
                        content.downloadStatus = holder.status;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (content.downloadProgress != 0f) {
                        content.downloadProgress = 0f;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                    if (content.downloadStatus != -1) {
                        content.downloadStatus = -1;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                }

                // Update with elapsed (to be done)

                // File exists?
                File file = Utils.getFilepath(content.getFilename());
                if (content.exists != file.exists()) {
                    content.exists = file.exists();
                    content.dirty = true;
                }

                // Is this the currently playing content
                if (currentContent != null && content.mp3.equals(currentContent.mp3)) {
                    if (content.isPlaying != isPlaying) {
                        content.isPlaying = isPlaying;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                    if (content.isPaused != isPaused) {
                        content.isPaused = isPaused;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (content.isPlaying != false) {
                        content.isPlaying = false;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                    if (content.isPaused != false) {
                        content.isPaused = false;
                        content.dirty = true;
                    }
                }

                if (content.dirty) {
                    DatabaseManager.getInstance().createOrUpdateContent(content);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class UpdateHolder {
        public String mp3;
        public int status;
        public boolean played;
        public float progress;
        public boolean exists = false;
        public boolean isPlaying = false;
        public boolean isPaused = false;
        //public int elapsed;
        //public int duration;
    }

}
```

I couldn't find the issue in it. I'm stuck here for last 40 hours. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you imported `PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener` with its right package name?? Problem is because of just wrong import or import statement is missing.

Comment: it is imported with right package name and it is not giving me any error at import. it is fine at import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher;

Comment: So `PullToRefreshAttacher` class is in `uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library` package??

Comment: yes it is in this package.

Comment: How did you import `PullToRefresh` library?

Comment: @Romadja right click on project porperties->android and at bottom added it by clicking add button

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using old version of the library. I found that `PullToRefreshAttacher` doesn't contain `OnRefreshListener`. (https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/actionbarpulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshAttacher.java)

Try to import `uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.listeners.OnRefreshListener;` and use it instead of `PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener`.

Comment: I've imported import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.listeners.OnRefreshListener; but issue remain same. my PullToRefreshAttacher contains OnRefreshListener.

Comment: Did you change `implements PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener` to `implements OnRefreshListener` when you import `uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.listeners.OnRefreshListener;`?

Comment: now it is giving me the error at mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(mListview, this); this method is in the PullToRefreshAttacher, but it is not getting it.

Comment: You can also import `uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher` isn't it?

Comment: I'v imported but not working. import is successful but imported class methods and data members are not being fetched. very strange to me :(