# Android - On Item click of listview not responding

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

[image]

What I'm trying to do is when I click on any item of the list that will change the color of text and the drawable 
this is my getview method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_item, null);
        convertView.setFocusable(false);

        final TextView mItemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title_tv);
        mItemTitle.setText(mNavDrawerItems.get(position).getmItemTitle());

        final ImageView mTitleIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon_iv);
        mTitleIcon.setImageDrawable(
                mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mNavDrawerItems.get(position).getmItemIcon()));

        if (position == 0)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_header, null);
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            /*
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    setColorAndDrawble(mItemTitle, mTitleIcon,
                            mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.last_news_click_color),
                            mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_class_news_click));
                }
            });
            */
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    setColorAndDrawble(mItemTitle, mTitleIcon,
                            mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.public_chat_click_color),
                            mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_public_chat_click));
                }
            });
        }
        else if (position == 3)
        {
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    setColorAndDrawble(mItemTitle, mTitleIcon,
                            mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.messages_click_color),
                            mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_messages_click));
                }
            });
        }
        else if (position == 4)
        {
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    setColorAndDrawble(mItemTitle, mTitleIcon,
                            mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.results_click_color),
                            mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_results_click));
                }
            });
        }

        return convertView;
}

private void setColorAndDrawble(TextView textView, ImageView imageView, int color, Drawable drawble)
{
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawble);
    textView.setTextColor(color);
}
```

the problem is now the listener of listview doesn't work. Why?

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());    

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Log.e("SlideMenuClickListener", position + "");
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title_tv);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.last_news_click_color));
            Log.e("textView", textView.getText() + "");
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can be seen as wrong, You should instead create a class and a Custom Adapter for each listview item, also you shouldn't use `setOnClickListener` for each element.

Using of a ViewHolder is advised too.

**For further details also check [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) link or the official documentation.**

Answer (score 0):

When you set a click listener for a row, this blocks the normal click processing for the `ListView`. You can fix this by moving the entire logic for updating the row into your `onItemClick` method. (You already have the text color change logic duplicated there.)

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.e("SlideMenuClickListener", position + "");
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title_tv);

        if (position > 0) {
            textView.setTextColor(getTextColor(position),
                textView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor());
            final ImageView titleIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_icon_iv);
            titleIcon.setImageDrawable(getImage(position));
            parent.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);
        }
        Log.e("textView", textView.getText() + "");
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }

    private int getTextColor(int position, int defaultColor) {
        final Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        int color = defaultColor;
        switch (position) {
            case 2: color = res.getColor(R.color.public_chat_click_color); break;
            case 3: color = res.getColor(R.color.messages_click_color);    break;
            case 4: color = res.getColor(R.color.results_click_color);     break;
        }
        return color;
    }

    private Drawable getImage(int position) {
        int resId = mNavDrawerItems.get(position).getmItemIcon()); // default
        switch (position) {
            case 2: resId = R.drawable.ic_public_chat_click; break;
            case 3: resId = R.drawable.ic_messages_click;    break;
            case 4: resId = R.drawable.ic_results_click;     break;
        }
        return getContext().getDrawable(resId);
    }
}
```

You can improve the overall performance of this approach by using the view holder pattern (as recommended in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)). This involves setting the tag for each row to a small object that has references to the text and image views for that row.

Comment: @user3871129 - I don't know. I tried to imitate your code, but maybe I got it wrong. You should be able to fix the logic. The important idea is the approach: make the changes in `onItemClick`.

Comment: still the same problem the color of text view and icon didn't change

Comment: @user3871129 - Hm. You may need to add a line of code to force the row to refresh (as described in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123083/android-listview-refresh-single-row).) I updated my sample code to show how that might work, and fixed a couple of other obvious problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by add setOnTouchListener to convertView in my adpater class :) and it's work fine right now

Comment: Could you post the code that finally worked for you?