# Issue with update single row listview and how to store and load listview multiple choices

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm working in my personal project, and I want to build an activity to activate some functions correspond to the items in listview. Just like this :

(Sorry I'm very brand new here so I cannot attach picture)

[What we should have in previous activity's listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIIKa.png)

[Multiple Choices in ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17j8N.png)

My problem is :

- I dont know how to store and load the listview multiple choice when I go back
- I cannot show the name of choices in textview of the single row in listview of previous acitivity

I did try with some options in our forum such as this link [Android ListView Refresh Single Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123083/android-listview-refresh-single-row) but I have to use button to click, it cannot work automatically when I used getIntent(), always pops up error and close my app.

Now I have to force to getIntent() from a StringArray and set new Adapter to the listview with String[] pass from multiple choices listview's activity

Here is the code I use so far :

***main_listview.xml* and *list_devices.xml* are exactly the same**

```
<Button

    android:id="@+id/getchoice"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Get Choice"

    />

<ListView

    android:id="@+id/list"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
```

***AndroidListViewActivity.java* => Main activity (Activity A)**

```
String[] listContent = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
};

String[] subtitle ={
        "Tap to set","Tap to set",
        "Tap to set","Tap to set",
        "Tap to set",
};

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_listview);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getchoice);

    if (extras != null)
    {
        String[] getExtra = extras.getStringArray("part1");
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, listContent, getExtra);
    }
    else
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, listContent, subtitle);

    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int start = myList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View view = myList.getChildAt(1 -start);
            myList.getAdapter().getView(1, view, myList);
            TextView getabc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            getabc.setText(getText);
            //     break;
        }});

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(position == 0) {
                //code specific to first list item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your First Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent mainact = new Intent (AndroidListViewActivity.this, ListDevices.class);
                startActivity(mainact);
            }

            else if(position == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your First Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent mainact = new Intent (AndroidListViewActivity.this, ListDevices.class);
                startActivity(mainact);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Second Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if(position == 2) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Third Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(position == 3) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Forth Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(position == 4) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Place Your Fifth Option Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

***mylist.xml***

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tap to set"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

***ListDevices.java* ===> Second Activity (Activity B)**

```
public class ListDevices extends Activity {

ListView myList;

Button getChoice;
String selected ="", selected1="", selected2="", selected3="", selected4="";
String[] abc = { selected,selected1,selected2,selected3,selected4 };
Bundle extras;
Intent intent_new;
String[] listContent = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
};

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_devices);

    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getchoice);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter

            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,

            listContent);

    intent_new = new Intent (ListDevices.this, AndroidListViewActivity.class);
    extras = new Bundle();

    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

            SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();

            for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                    abc[0] += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                }
            }

            for (int i=0 ; i < abc.length ; i++)
            {
                if (abc[i] == "")
                    abc[i] = abc[i].replace("","Tap to set");
            }

            intent_new.putExtra("part1",abc);
            startActivity(intent_new);

        }});
}
```

**Here is my ArrayAdapter : *MyListAdapter.java***

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] maintitle;
private final String[] subtitle;

public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] maintitle,String[] subtitle) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, maintitle);
    this.context=context;
    this.maintitle=maintitle;
    this.subtitle=subtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return maintitle.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return maintitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    TextView subtitleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    titleText.setText(maintitle[position]);
    subtitleText.setText(subtitle[position]);

    return rowView;

};
```

Here is what I have so far :

[Activity A before choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOmFu.png)

[Multiple choices in Activity B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf2SZ.png)

[Activity A after choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPCs6.png)

I'm still wonder for a better solution to expand my knowledge and get more experiences, please kindly give me some because I think mine is not good and convenient for future use.

Thank you for watching and sorry for my English too.